# Everthing is fine but flutter project gives error while build or debug

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, build, kernel

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM M115F in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

/C:/Users/91984/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/modal_bottom_sheet-2.1.2/lib/src/material_with_modal_page_route.dart:4:1: Error: 'ModalBottomSheetRoute' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart' and 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/src/bottom_sheet_route.dart'.
import '../modal_bottom_sheet.dart';
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/91984/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/modal_bottom_sheet-2.1.2/lib/src/bottom_sheets/material_bottom_sheet.dart:28:13: Error: 'ModalBottomSheetRoute' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart' and 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/src/bottom_sheet_route.dart'.
      .push(ModalBottomSheetRoute<T>(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/91984/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/modal_bottom_sheet-2.1.2/lib/src/bottom_sheets/material_bottom_sheet.dart:50:10: Error: A value of type 'Object?' can't be returned from an async function with return type 'Future<T?>'.
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
  return result;
         ^
/C:/Users/91984/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/modal_bottom_sheet-2.1.2/lib/src/bottom_sheets/bar_bottom_sheet.dart:102:13: Error: 'ModalBottomSheetRoute' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/bottom_sheet.dart' and 'package:modal_bottom_sheet/src/bottom_sheet_route.dart'.
      .push(ModalBottomSheetRoute<T>(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/91984/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/modal_bottom_sheet-2.1.2/lib/src/bottom_sheets/bar_bottom_sheet.dart:125:10: Error: A value of type 'Object?' can't be returned from an async function with return type 'Future<T?>'.
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
  return result;
         ^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1151

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I have done:

- Flutter clean
- Flutter upgrade
- Pub upgrade
- Pub outdated and major versions
- Invalidate caches
- Deleted .gradle, local.properties, .darttool, .idea

But it shows the error while build apk.

Comment: Here is same open issue in Repository - https://github.com/jamesblasco/modal_bottom_sheet/issues/328. as per one of the suggestion 
Use the prerelease version https://pub.dev/packages/modal_bottom_sheet/versions/3.0.0-pre.  OR you can use some other plug-in which provide same features.